# Why ElasticBeans talk shows that the Environment health as Degraded & 100 % of CPU is in use while instance shows normal CPU

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Health tab on ElasticBeanstalk environment shows 100 % of CPU is in use.
[image]

health monitor also shows these metrics

[image]

but when I visit the instance monitoring tab, it shows the CPU utilization as normal

[image]
[image]

running a top command shows this screen

[image]

What I can notice is the ST is high so what could be the reason that ElasticBens talk shows loaded CPU while EC2 Monitor shows normal?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause of this issue is that the instance type is t2.micro which are burst-able and this means there are CPU credit that is given to the instance when it process below baseline and there is also launch credit

at my case, it seemed that the instance consumed all the launch credit and also the accumulated CPU credit when it processed above the baseline (Brust)

[image]

when this case happens and the instance has no CPU credit, Amazon hypervisor throttled the CPU and increased the Stealing Time to 76%

[image]

How I solved this issue?

I added an extra instance to work alongside the throttled one which reduced the load on this instance, it then started accumulating credit and the stealing time went down

[image]

[image]